# RoboVM UIAccessibilityTraits errors

Tags: java, ios, voiceover, robovm

I was playing around with the UIAccessibility for iOS to work with VoiceOver. However, I can't get it to work and I get a weird error.

Here is the code (snippet):

```
UIAccessibilityElement accessibilityElement = new UIAccessibilityElement(iosAccessibility);

        accessibilityElement.setAccessibilityFrame(new CGRect(x, y, width, height));

        if (item.GetName() != null)
            accessibilityElement.setAccessibilityLabel(item.GetName());
        else
            accessibilityElement.setAccessibilityLabel("Default Name");

        if (item.GetDescription() != null)
            accessibilityElement.setAccessibilityHint(item.GetDescription());
        else
            accessibilityElement.setAccessibilityHint("Default Description");

        if (item.GetAccessibilityCode() == item.Get_Libraries_Interface_Item__NOT_ACCESSIBLE_())
            accessibilityElement.setAccessibilityElement(false);
        else
            accessibilityElement.setAccessibilityElement(true);

        accessibilityElement.setAccessibilityTraits(UIAccessibilityTraits.Image);

        // Add the accessibility element to the list
        accessibilityElements.add(accessibilityElement);

        // Inform iOS that the accessibility elements have changed
        UIAccessibilityGlobals.postNotification(UIAccessibilityNotification.LayoutChangedNotification, accessibilityElement);
```

Error: class java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError, Optional @GlobalValue method org/robovm/apple/uikit/UIAccessibilityTraits.NoneValue()J not bound

Am I doing something wrong?